# How to bring back File Explorer as the default folder browser in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Adobe Bridge is being the folder browser in Windows 8 instead of file explorer. When I double click a folder, Adobe Bridge comes up. I looked in control panel -> Folder Options. Also looked in 'Default Programs'. I can't find the setting to set the program for folder browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [folders opening in bridge by default instead of explorer](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3093234?tstart=0) you can simply remove the handler from the registry to restore default behavior.

Just remove the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Bridge`